# Explicit cast definition fails to operate when object held as interface version

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code.

```
public static void TestCast()
{
    ILegendKey key = new DataLine();
    PlotLine line = (PlotLine)key; // this throws System.InvalidCastException even though cast defined
}

public interface ILegendKey
{
    string Text { get; }
    Color Color { get; }
}

public class PlotLine
{
    public PlotLine()
    {
        Color = Color.Black;
    }

    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class DataLine : ILegendKey
{
    public DataLine()
    {
        Info = new DataLineInfo();
        Text = "";
    }

    public DataLineInfo Info { get; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color
    {
        get => Info.Color;
        set => Info.Color = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator PlotLine(DataLine value) => value.Info;
}

public class DataLineInfo : PlotLine, ILegendKey
{
    public DataLineInfo() : base()
    {
        Text = "";
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Even though I have an explicitly defined cast operator from DataLine to PlotLine, I am getting a "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DataLine' to type 'PlotLine'" in the above `TestCast` function and not sure why. My project is compiled using .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: You are trying to cast an `ILegendKey` to a `PlotLine` which is an invalid cast - the type implementing `ILegendKey` is not constrained (any class can implement `ILegendKey`) so there's no guarantee that the cast is valid. If you were to declare the type as `DataLine` the cast would work. e.g. if you implement the `ILegendKey` interface in a new class `MyNewClass`, it's not valid to cast `MyNewClass` to `PlotLine`

Comment: Charleh: Thanks, I can follow that. This leaves me with the rhetorical question of why does the exception say unable to cast from 'DataLine' rather than unable to cast from 'ILegendKey'? This just makes debugging difficult as it appears the runtime recognizes that the object is a `DataLine`, which could be cast and not just the generic `ILegendKey` which can't.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good question - I'm not actually sure, maybe a question for someone that knows more about the internals in .NET.

My question though is when would you want to cast like this? Usually interfaces are there for a reason - casting from an interface to a concrete type is sometimes (usually?) bad practice and suggests maybe the design has issues.

Comment: In this case, I have a plot with a legend - in the legend, I have the variable name being plotted and the value of said line at requested point. The user can right-click on the legend key to change the color of the line. To make this simpler, I made the two classes directly ILegendKey's for displaying the variable name and value and made the latter also be the line. This way, I could extract the line from the legend to change its color without needing to do a lookup. I was hoping casting would give me the line directly rather than needing a switch between DataLine and DataLineInfo.